# How to send mail in hotmail using Python?

Tags: python, hotmail

Is there a way to login my hotmail account and send mails with a Python program?

Comment: Is there a reason for using Hotmail and not the nearest SMTP server you have at hand?

Comment: I want to reach my hotmail contacts and not be marked as spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using their [SMTP server](http://techblissonline.com/hotmail-pop3-and-smtp-settings/):

- User name: Your Windows Live ID, for example yourname@hotmail.com
- Password: The password you usually use to sign in to Hotmail or Windows Live
- SMTP server: smtp.live.com (Port 25) {Note: If port 25 has been blocked in your network or by your ISP, you can set SMTP port to 587 with TLS or SSL Encryption depending on the client in use}
- Authentication required? Yes (this matches your POP username and password)
- TLS/SSL required? Yes

Use [smtplib](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html) to send mail. You can find some examples [here](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html#email-examples).